# JetBrains Rider enable-migrations for ASP.NET MVC on mac

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, jetbrains-ide

I have JetBrains Rider 2018.3 on macOS Mojave. I created an ASP.NET MVC project, installed entity framework 6.2. I added the connection string to web.config. But, I don't know how to configure app.config. I want to enable-migrations for this project to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server. I googled it and found this link [Entity Framework Support in Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/). However, I am not able to find **Tools | Entity Framework | Initial setup**. I was wondering if you could help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I have posted the question I read the link again. I noticed I missed the point **project context menu**. I right clicked on project name and I found Tools.

Comment: I'm not able to find it in rider 2019.3, I'm using entity framework core, any chance you might know how?

Comment: Oh, I think it's not yet supported in EF Core yet, it will only work from the command line by installing dotnet-ef tool.

Comment: It is still not working even using dotnet-ef tool

Answer (score 1):

When you're done adding the EntityFramework nuget package, just right-click on the project, and use the Entity Framework options available. See my screenshot below.

[image]