# Rider doesn't have EF as an option in tools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rider

I am trying to add a migration to my MVC NET.Core project

https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/ shows

> After installing the EntityFramework NuGet package, we can initialize Entity Framework in our project from the project context menu, under Tools | Entity Framework | Initial setup.

[JetBrains Rider enable-migrations for ASP.NET MVC on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135137/jetbrains-rider-enable-migrations-for-asp-net-mvc-on-mac) actually points out you have to right click on the project and choose tools.

However, I don't have the option

[image]

More research and it shows how I can do this via the terminal in Rider. https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

This is where I **think** the problem might be (or the following is a red herring)

In the terminal, I CD into my project. I enter `dotnet restore` and it completes

I then type `dotnet ef` and I'm told

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

I am totally baffled why this is the case.

I have a work around - it works perfectly in Visual Studio, but I'm trying to learn another IDE and would like to get past this

Any thoughts? Ultimately, the best option is to have the Tools > EF option in rider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve the command line issue

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-1-and-entity-framework-6-4/

CD into your project then run

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

As per @Niels Filter  comment, you may need

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0

Comment: This worked, thank you. I just had to add the version as well (I was using 3.1.0) `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0`

Comment: The proposed solution fixes the command line issue but in my case it does not solve the not existing entry in the tools menu. Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I installed the plugin Entity Framework Core UI and it resolved the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AJU5.png)

Go to Tools>Entity Framework Core and you can see all the options for migration

Answer (score 0):

According to this official post from jetbrains https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/09/running-entity-framework-core-commands-rider/

cd into your project folder and type the below command

```
dotnet ef
```

if you get any error then type the below command

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

After that, following code first database configuration, type the below command to make migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations add "migration message"
```

Type the below command to update the database migrations.

```
dotnet ef database update "update database"
```

Hope this helps.